# how to create "" for a column containging duplicate values

Tags: excel-2010

So I have a worksheet with multiple columns and one of the columns contains description of the product.

I have multiple lines of apples and multiple lines or orange.

[image]

Is there a forumla that can display only one cell with the product description with apples, oranges, and leave rest of the duplicates blank ("").

[image]

Comment: `SUMIF` seems like the obvious one.  `=SumIf(A:A,"apple",C:C)` would display sum of all sales of "apple".

Comment: can you show sample data? maybe edit the question or add a sample file to google drive? what you want should be possble via v look ups or filters

Comment: I did try the sumif function, but it wasn't the result i was looking for. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't really recommend using blanks there.  Your original data setup is perfect for a flat file and makes performing calculations like Countif/s, Sumif/s, etc really easy.

If you absolutely must change it, you could use column E as a helper with this formula starting in cell E2 and copied down (note, this formula requires that the data be sorted by Product as shown in your example):

```
=IF(B2=B1,"",B2)
```

Then copy the helper column -> select B2 -> right-click -> paste special -> values

And delete the helper column.